# FIlling data with pm3d function

Tags: linux, unix, graphics, 3d, gnuplot

How, to avoid pm3d to fill data? I have some regions at the same z value, and some at the other value, but when i plot them, pm3d override ones with larger z value

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal working example](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces and illustrates your problem, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color of a single quadrangle depends on the value of its four corners. You can use the `corners2color` option to `set pm3d` to select how the individual corners contribute to the color. Using e.g.

```
set pm3d corners2color c1
```

would always use the same corner (e.g. lower left) to determine the color. Beware, that the assignment `c1` may depend on the data.

Valid values in version 4.6.5 are `mean`, `geomean`, `median`, `min`, `max`, `c1`, `c2`, `c3`, `c4`.

See also `help corners2color` and the [last pm3d demo](http://gnuplot.info/demo/pm3d.html).